# Php: Arrays Conept Issue

Tags: php

I'm Working with php arrays.When i declare array like this

```
$array = array("Hello","World",);
```

and debug this debugger show like this

```
$array = {array} [2]
 0 = "Hello"
 1 = "World"
```

I know 0 for first element and 1 for second element but when i declear

```
$array4 = [7];     //$array4: {7} [1]
```

debugger show

```
$array4 = {array} [1]
 0 = 7
```

I don't know why it show like this does it not mean i declare array for 7 elements why does it show {7} in curly braces and [1] in subscript.

Comment: you have created an array with one item, the integer `7`. Php arrays are more like lists or dictionary's in more c like languages - you do not initialize them with a fixed number of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is not Javascript. `array(7)` and `[7]` do not create a new array with 7 elements. It creates a new array with a SINGLE new element, whose value is `7`.

Answer (score -1):

It works that way because this is PHP and not C++. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php Some very basic reading would have prevented this question.